# Massachusetts Condominium Code Requirement?

Tags: code-compliance

I own a condominium in Massachusetts and recently had water damage inside a wall that is shared with the adjoining unit. The drywall has been removed but surprise,no insulation was present. That explains the issue many of us have with noise transfer between units. The building was built in 2006 and the repair person claims code didn't require it in 2006. I find that very hard to believe. Does anyone know what the code requirement in 2006 was and what is the present day code requirement for insulation in the newly repaired wall? Thank you for any insight.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that's unfortunately common in units which were manufactured for sale rather than commissioned by buyers. Builders always have the temptation to skimp on anything that critical first buyer won't notice, unless they are being watched by said buyer or are under a contract which gives them a bigger budget up front. It's been true for apartment buildings, it's been true for single-family tract homes, it's true for condos.

As long as fire code is met, there's no explicit soundproofing requirement. This is one of the things your inspector should be looking into before you buy. And "insulation" is usually not enough for soundproofing anyway; sound gets coupled through the studs more efficiently than through the air gap, so you need to either build with offset studs and each wall attached to only the ones offset in its direction or install other materials to let one wall vibrate without shaking the other.

High-end condos should be designed with this in mind. (Though I'm only saying "should".) On the lower end, especially condos converted from apartment buildings of other mass construction, I'd be surprised to see sound isolation unless whoever was doing the condo construction/conversion thought they could use it as a selling feature and recapture the investment in higher prices.

If you want to spend the money and give up floor space, you can put sound isolation inside your unit to make up for what isn't there now. Assuming your condo association doesn't  object. (If you own a condo, you may not be able to afford *not* to be on that board...)

Otherwise, all you can really do is work with your neighbor to agree on quiet hours, and keep earplugs handy for the occasional late activity. And try to keep your quiet spaces away from the shared wall. Basically, the same compromises as living in an apartment building.

Condos, except for built-to-order places like the duplex two families I know are sharing or the "intentional community" co-housing developments other friends are in, risk having all the disadvantages of renting plus all the disadvantages of owning. I've seen some -- mostly, as I say, on the high end -- which were built with this sort of thing in mind and can handle a noisy party in one unit without much inconvenience to the neighbors. But you generally get what you pay for... or at least don't get what you weren't willing to pay for.

Comment: There's an appendix to the IRC, [Appendix AK](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/appendix-ak-sound-transmission), that actually sets some sound transmission requirements. In the current _draft_ of the [Massachusetts building code](https://www.mass.gov/doc/10th-edition-total-version-1213/download), they have it marked "Adopted in Full." In the near future, then, new construction in Massachusetts may have some sound proofing requirements.

Comment: (Next time, if there's a next time. This is one of the things you can ask a home inspector to check out before final purchase negotiations. And/or talk to the folks in other units to find out what their opinions are.)

Comment: @popham: Great! But MA has a huge amount of existing housing stock (though apparently not enough) so unless you're buying something newly constructed you're  probably still stuck with either accepting as it is or spending to improve it.  One of the reasons I finally bought a house back in the 2000's was that I wanted not to have to worry so much about noise from neighbors or my 2AM activity bothering them.

Comment: @keshlam -- recent IBC editions *do* incorporate an explicit soundproofing requirement (it's IBC 1206.2), and this goes back as far as 2006 (although it was 1207.2 in the 2006 IBC)

Comment: Thanks; good to know. That's still only new construction and major renovations, though, right? (I live in a 125-year-old house; luckily most of the important updates were done before I bought it, at least up to 1960's standards.)